# is there a way to get controller path for an ajax call within a partial view?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

So I have a partial view that is just a widget that allows users to select dates and filter results by the dates. This partial view can go on many pages so I would like to completely decouple it & reuse it.
I wanted to add event listeners that submit whatever form the date partial view is in.

in my main view I have

```
@{using (Html.BeginForm("getActivityManagementTwoActivities", "CallCenter", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "ActivityTwoForm" }))
    {
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="float:right;">
                <div class="dateWrapper">@{ Html.RenderPartial("_DateFilter"); } </div>
            </div> 
            //... 
       @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ActivityManagementCollapseComponent", Model);
}
```

my controllers:

```
    public async Task<PartialViewResult> getActivityManagementTwoActivities(DateFilterModel filters, int results = 25)
    {
        var model = await GetFullAndPartialViewModel(filters, results);
        return PartialView("_ActivityManagementCollapseComponent", model);
    }
```

my date partial view:

```
<div class="date-text-collapsible">
<form method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right; vertical-align: top; width: 160px">
                Time filter:
            </td>
            <td style="display:inline-block; width:150px">
                <input id="radio1" name="radioToggle" type="radio"> Recent
                <select id="timeFilter" name="timeFilter" class="hokage">
                    <option value="Last 30 days">at least 18</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <input id="radio2" name="radioToggle" class="radioTimeFilter" type="radio"> Date Range
                <div id="dateContent" class="radio-content" style="display:none;">
                    <input id="txtDateOneFilter" type="text" style="width: 80px;" placeholder="Start Date" name="dateStart" class="hokage" />&nbsp;to&nbsp;
                    <input id="txtDateTwoFilter" type="text" style="width: 80px;" placeholder="End Date" name="dateEnd" class="hokage" />
                </div>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>    
    </table>
</form>
```

I tried adding event listeners this way:

```
    var inputDateBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("hokage");
    addOnChangeListenersToSubmit(inputDateBoxes);
    function addOnChangeListenersToSubmit(arrayOfElements) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfElements.length; i++) {
        arrayOfElements[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
          this.form.submit();
        })
      }
    }
```

but this way fails it only returns the partial view by itself. I'm thinking that this can't be a form and I need to specify ajax or something. How can I update the partial view from within the date filter partial?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of razor syntax you can use to get the controller name and the action name:

```
string controllerName = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();        
string actionName = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

You could build from there.

Comment: Thanks, let me see if I can implement it